# Why does my includegraphics keep moving around when I move the node in tikzpicture?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to create the following figure

[image]

Below is my sample code. I can't seem to get AR on the correct position. Everytime I change the x position the entire figure moves about. How do I fix everything in place?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfig}

\title{test}
\author{test}%

\date{January 2022}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\tikzset
{%
  label/.style={scale=0.7,fill=white,thick,draw=white!80,anchor=south west,align=left},
}

\def\lsep{-0.2}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\hspace{-7.5cm}
\subfloat{
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[label] at (-0.5,\lsep)    {\strut$A^{L}$};
    \node[label] at (-0.5+4,\lsep)  {\strut$A^{R}$};
    {\includegraphics[width=0.4\columnwidth,height=5\columnheight]{example-image-a}}\hspace{1cm}
    {\includegraphics[width=0.4\columnwidth,height=5\columnheight]{example-image-a}}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{figure}

\section{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your example doesn't work for me `\columnheight` is undefined.

Comment: I'm actually a bit surprised you get those images at all, given that they're inside the `tikzpicture`, but not in a `node`. But do you need TikZ here, or can you use something like `$A^{L}$ \includegraphics[width=0.4\columnwidth,height=1cm]{example-image-a} \raisebox{1cm}{$A^{R}$} \includegraphics[width=0.4\columnwidth,height=1cm]{example-image-a}`? Edit: don't know if that `\raisebox` is needed, not sure exactly how those labels should be aligned.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code. The four elements are positioned relative to each other. So the `tikzpicture` will move as a whole.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfig}

\usepackage{showframe}

\title{test}
\author{test}%

\date{January 2022}

\begin{document}
    
    \maketitle
    
    \tikzset
    {%
        label/.style={scale=0.7,
            draw,
            fill=white,
            thick,
            draw=white!80,
            above right= -1.5ex and -4.0ex,
            align=left
        },
    }
    
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \centering
        \subfloat{
            \begin{tikzpicture}         
                \node[inner sep=0] (image1) {\includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth,height=0.02\linewidth]{example-image-a}};
                \node[inner sep=0, right=1cm of image1.east] (image2) {\includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth,height=0.02\linewidth]{example-image-b}};
                \node[label] at  (image1.west)  {\strut$A^{L}$};
                \node[label] at  (image2.west)   {\strut$A^{R}$};
            \end{tikzpicture}
        }
    \end{figure}
    
    \section{Introduction}
    
\end{document}
```